# Excel: How to add a plus sign to numbers and how to copy actual value of that cell (+876345558)

Tags: excel

I have a subscriber list with emails and phone numbers.
The row with the phone numbers are plain numbers (like 98734543).

With format > custom > "+0;-0;0"
I managed to transform the plain number into +98734543.

Ok - and now I feel stupid. (I wasn't able to google the solution... oh man)

How do I transform the value of the cell (I guess it's a formula now) into an actual value that I can copy into a new row in a way that the cell value isn't just (still) 98734543 but +98734543?

I tried Paste Value (E) but this didn't work either.

Help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the cell you want the result: **=TEXT(A1|"+0")**

A1 referencing the source cell. Formatting options to the right of the pipe sign.

Depending on your version of Excel it might be a comma separator instead of pipe.

Since your source is a list without any format, this seems like a better solution: output a list with the wanted format.